# its possible to retrieve data from one session? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

Is this possible to retrieve data from mysql table from one session?

For example I have the `Session["username"]` that show me the name of the user.

but If I want to know the gender of the user, I can know it through only one session?

For example `Session["username"].gender` ??

instead of opening another Session for gender?

someone told me to open a class in app_code:

```
public class user
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}
```

But I dont know how to use it with only one session.

If its possible, show me how pls!

Comment: You store an instance of the class in the session that describes the user. Apart from that, I'm not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: my question is how can i get to a gender of a specific user with one session.
for example I have a username called "gamer" and his gender is "male" how can I get to his gender with one Session["username"] and not with Session["gender"] ?

Comment: You would store an instance of a `user` object in the session. Then later you check to see if the session contains an object there. If it is, cast it to the user type (because it will just be an `object`) and then you can access the gender property.